# Can a HTTP redirect instruct the client to strip a specific header from the request?

Tags: http, amazon-s3

We have a service that redirects the user to an object in an S3 bucket. The authentication for that request is stored in the query portion of the URL.

I understand that the spec doesn't specify what is to be done with request headers in the case of a redirect, but implementations I've seen will strip the `Authorization` header when HTTP Basic is used.

What's interesting is that when we call our service through HTTP Basic authentication, it works fine. The client strips the `Authorization` header from the request and the file is delivered from S3.

But when we call our service using OAuth bearer tokens the `Authorization` header is left in for the redirect, causing S3 to return a `400` error response.

Is there a way for the server's redirect response to instruct the client to strip the `Authorization` header before accessing the response's `Location` header?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've encountered the same problem, and best work-around I've come up with is to enable the service to accept bearer tokens via HTTP Basic authentication -- hacking it to pass the token as if it were the username or password.

Comment: I never did figure it out. We worked around it by not using HTTP redirects, and have the client application redirect to the URL specified in the response. In other words, we implemented our own redirect logic.