# Authorization header - should be sent or not?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, postman

I'm using WEBAPI (asp.net) with vs2015.

In my `web.config` I have this rewrite url rule which redirects `HTTP` to `HTTPS`  (I know I can do it via HSTS but that's not the point here):

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action redirectType="Temporary" type="Redirect"  url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

The rule is working fine.

Also , I've created a self signed certificate and made chrome to trust it.

(es.com , is  my localhost  , via hosts file)

And it is trusted :

[image]

But Something is not clear to me.

When I use POSTMAN to make an **HTTP** request , I get a 307 redirect response header which redirects to  `HTTPS` and it does send the Authorization header  , I do see it in my webapi :

[image]

Here is the network tab:

[image]

The first request was `HTTP` , then server sends `HTTPS` redirect
and as you can see  - WEBAPI did get the Authorization header. Here is the proof that the SECOND request did send the Authorization header :

[image]

Now fiddler.

I compose a new request to HTTP :

[image]

I do get a response with 307

[image]

But the second request **doesn't send** the authorization header :

[image]

And hence - WEBAPI doesn't get its value :

[image]

**Questions**

1 ) Why doesn't fiddler send the Authorization header ? And How can I make it send it

2 ) I think I read somewhere that Authorization headers is NOT being sent on redirects [BY DESIGN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671822/859154). If so - does postman is working improperly  ?

What am I missing here ?

NB 
*I already know that I can create a custom header which will contain the authorization value , and it will be sent also on redirects. But that's not my question.*

Comment: It is also my understanding that Authorization header should not be preserved during redirects, so if Postman is keeping it I suppose that it is due to some improper implementation.