# How do I get log output from JwtSecurityTokenHandler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application project that uses JWT tokens for authenticating the Web API that's built-in to the project. It works fine when I run it locally on my machine, but when I deploy it to Azure (with identical environment and app-settings) it simply returns empty HTTP 401 responses to requests from my authenticated clients and I need to find out why so I can fix it.

I enabled logging of every detail in ASP.NET Core, however I never received any useful output.

First, I added `Serilog.AspNetCore` and the Console sink to the project through NuGet, then configured logging at `Verbose` level in `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .CreateLogger();

        CreateWebHostBuilder( args ).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(String[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .ConfigureLogging( (ctx, cfg ) =>
            {
                cfg.ClearProviders();
            } )
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

But when I run my web-application on Azure (with console `stdout` logging to file) I got this output:

```
[04:13:10 Verbose] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker
Authorization Filter: Before executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.

[04:13:10 Verbose] 
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
HandleAuthenticateAsync called

[04:13:10 Debug] 
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.

[04:13:10 Information] 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService
Authorization failed.

[04:13:10 Verbose] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker
Authorization Filter: After executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.

[04:13:10 Information] 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker
Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.

[04:13:10 Verbose] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker
Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.

[04:13:10 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult
Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["Bearer"]).

[04:13:10 Verbose] 
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
Forwarding challenge to scheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt
```

Note how despite verbose logging, the error messages (repeated below) don't give me any explanation:

```
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
Authorization failed.
```

I dug around the ASP.NET Core Security source-code to see that `JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync` doesn't do much logging of its own, but it does call into the not-open-sourced `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which does normally do a lot of logging, including detailed reasons (e.g. (with `IDX10209`-type error codes in strings), but I don't know why it isn't outputting anything I can capture.

How do I log messages from `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:

- My `HttpClient` (that was sending the HTTP `Authorization` header Bearer token) was **unintentionally** sending it to a `http://` URI that immediately received a 301 redirect to a `https://` URI. The redirect was performed by IIS without the ASP.NET Core pipeline getting involved.
- The `HttpClient` class does not re-send the `Authorization` header following a redirect (this is [by-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564961/authorization-header-is-lost-on-redirect)).

  - I never noticed this because my `HttpClient`'s received `HttpResponseMessage` had a reference to the *original* request which had the `Authorization` header, not the post-redirect request that lacked the header. I had to use Fiddler with the HTTPS proxy to see the second request was lacking the  `Authorization` header.
- When `IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler` or ASP.NET Core's own `JwtBearerHandler` receives a request with no `Authorization` header it does not call into  `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` at all. To see this, open the `JwtBearerHandler.cs` file in the ASP.NET Core Security Git repo and look at `HandleAuthenticateAsync`: It has this logic:

  ```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
  {
      string authorization = Request.Headers["Authorization"];

      // If no authorization header found, nothing to process further
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
      {
          return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
      }
  ```
- So in my case, it never actually called `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` at all, hence the lack of output messages about JWT validation.
- However the output messages I did receive did not help. They're both misleading:

  - "AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated." should have been something like "AuthenticationScheme: No Bearer token was present in the request." instead.
  - And "Authorization failed." should have been "Authorization skipped because no token was present in the request."
- So in the end, the fix was to change the original request URI's scheme from `http://` to `https://`.