# Authorization Headers is missing using c# client

Tags: c#, django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, wsgi

I am developing a **RESTFUL API** using `django-rest-framework`. And for Authorization I choose to use Token Authorization (not JWT). Below is what I tried:

**Using POSTMAN (Works)**

```
headers: 
Authorization: Token 329367424fd30a876ccff05dbc5a18d86fe7158c
```

**Using C# Client (no working)**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token 329367424fd30a876ccff05dbc5a18d86fe7158c");
await client.GetAsync(<url>)

// Authentication credentials were not provided.
```

After I debug and override `TokenAuthentication` function, I realize that `Authorization headers` is being removed if requested from `C#` Client.

**EDIT**:

Actually I have tried using Javascript and it works also, I think the problem is C# `HttpClient`.

I tried

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization3", $"token {token}");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"token {token}");
```

and I debug `Authorization` function in python, and I found out only `Authorization3` was send to the server and `Authorization` wasn't

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `Authorization` header was missing is because of redirection. I am sorry for not posting my Uri string because I never though that is the problem.

My Uri string is `http://localhost:3000/module?query=123`. After calling `GetAsync` the Uri string become `http://localhost:3000/module/?query=123` (extra slash after module). So the library detect it is a **redirection**.

So my quick fix is just modified the url to `http://localhost:3000/module/?query=123`

For those who want know whether it was cause by redirection or not can checkout this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564961/authorization-header-is-lost-on-redirect/28671822#28671822)

Comment: You saved my day :) I queried a ASP.NET Core WebAPI that automatically redirected me to HTTPS when calling the respective HTTP endpoint, which caused my `Authorize`-Header to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpClient like below :

```cs
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                request.RequestUri = new Uri("url");
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                //request.Content = new StringContent("body", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");               
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Token 329367424fd30a876ccff05dbc5a18d86fe7158c");
                var getResponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
                using (HttpContent content = getResponse.Content)
                {
                    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Still no luck man, `Authentication credentials were not provided.`

Comment: Use fiddler application to compare the raw http request between c # and postman and see what's the differenet