# C# HttpClient cannot send authorization header to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to use C# HttpClient from ASP.NET MVC to make a request to an API. My API is running on .NET 6.0.

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue($"Bearer", $"{token}");
var serialized = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PutAsync(urlToSend, serialized);
```

Here is my code. I tried all the possibilities I saw on google. But when sending request, I can't send Authorization header.

I can send it with Postman.

Here is my API code:

```
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json", "text/plain")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(IResult))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(IResult))]
    [HttpPut("changeuserpassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUserPassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordCommand changePasswordCommand)
    {
        var accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
        return GetResponseOnlyResult(await Mediator.Send(changePasswordCommand));
    }
```

Note: In my _url, I use http, not https.

Comment: What do  you mean you can't send Authorization header. The request can't reach the API or in the API you can't get the value

Comment: Yes i can't get Authorization value from api with httpclient. but I can get when I post/put with Postman

Comment: Try httpClient.PutAsync to httpClient.PostAsync

Comment: i tried. not worked too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing my base url from HTTP to HTTPS.

I tried with Fiddler and I got the same problem when I request to HTTP.

So thanks to @olivier-duhart .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe the `[AllowAnonymous]`attribute remove the Authorization header from request just because it does not make sense if no authorization is needed.
Have you checked if the sent request contains the header using a tool like fiddler ?

Comment: I tried but it does not work too.

Comment: have you check the sent request with fiddler ? yiou first need to know whether the header disapears ? client or server side ? My guess is that t'is client side.

Comment: I don't know fiddler. I will do it. The second thing, When i add an other header like "custom-key" it works. The server API can see this header. But when I add "Authorization" it does not work. If I change to "Authorization-x" it works too.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, the problem gets solved by changing from HTTP to HTTPS is due to the fact that, the Authorization header gets stripped during redirects.
This behavior is for security concerns and is by design, as mentioned in the github discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26475).

The same behavior may not be seen when using Postman vs HttpClient for example, is due to the way that different clients, have differing mechanisms, by which the subsequent requests (following a response status 30X) to the redirect location are handled.

Also a great answer elsewhere on stackoverflow : [Authorization header is lost on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564961/authorization-header-is-lost-on-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Please review this link. Allow Anonymous will ignore the authentication header

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30546

I tried with the code. It seems working fine for me. Here is my code of console app

```
try
            {

                ChangePasswordCommand passobj = new ChangePasswordCommand() { password = "new password"};

                string _url = "https://localhost:44395/api/Values/";

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue($"Bearer", $"MYTOKEN");
                var serialized = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(passobj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PutAsync("changeuserpassword", serialized);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
            
            }
```

And here is controler Api

[AllowAnonymous]

```
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json", "text/plain")]
    
    [HttpPut("changeuserpassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUserPassword(ChangePasswordCommand changePasswordCommand)
    {
        var accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I did not work also when i did not use [AllowAnonymous], I tried this attribute after i get this issue.

Comment: Did u tried to add any other custom header except Authentication header?

Comment: Yes I do, and it worked. When I add "Authorization" API does not see it. But if I add "Authorization-x" it sees it.