# MAUI / Xamarin HttpClient on Android not sending Bearer Authorization Header on GET to API

Tags: xamarin, authorization, httpclient, maui

Struggling with MAUI to send a GET call from Android device to an API that requires Bearer auth. Setting the `Authorization` header in the `HttpClient` like so:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

However at the API endpoint, the `Authorization` header is not being received at all.

We have also tried sending an `HttpRequestMessage` with the `Authorization` header set explicitly, but still no dice.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the API we were sending to was running on both HTTP and HTTPS URLs.

In our android client config, we were sending to the HTTP URL.

Then we noticed that our API was set to redirect HTTP->HTTPS : `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

So it turns out that Auth headers are stripped on redirect!

[Authorization header is lost on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564961/authorization-header-is-lost-on-redirect)

When we changed our Android config to call the HTTPS URL directly, the Auth header started being received correctly.